# Proper use of tf.cond in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I have a question regarding the use of tf.cond. I am trying to run 2 images through a CNN and only backprop using the lower cross entropy loss value. The code is as follows:

`train_cross_entropy = tf.cond(train_cross_entropy1 < train_cross_entropy2, 
                               lambda: train_cross_entropy1,
                               lambda: train_cross_entropy2)`

Using this train_cross_entropy is just as slow as writing 

`train_cross_entropy = train_cross_entropy1 + train_cross_entropy2`

Which suggests to me that it is backpropping through both parts of the graph instead of just the one.
I would hope that it would be almost as fast as writing

`train_cross_entropy = train_cross_entropy1`

It would be greatly appreciated if anybody had any ideas on how to accomplish this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to move the gradient calculation inside the tf.cond like so:

```
    def f1(): 
        grads = tf.gradients(train_cross_entropy1, var_list, 
                             stop_gradients=[train_cross_entropy2])
        return grads
    def f2(): 
        grads = tf.gradients(train_cross_entropy2, var_list, 
                             stop_gradients=[train_cross_entropy1])
        return grads

    gradients = tf.cond(train_cross_entropy1 < train_cross_entropy2, f1, f2)
```

And then I can apply gradients later on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the same CNN for processing both images, this makes sense. Let's consider forward (input -> cost) and backward (backprop/gradients) computations separately.

For the forward computation, both inputs need to be processed for the conditional since the two cross entropy values need to be compared. Thus, the `tf.cond` case is no faster than adding the two costs.

For the backwards computation, there is actually no difference: In either case, the error needs to be backpropagated all the way from the output layer to the beginning of the network. Note that we are computing gradients with respect to the *variables* (network weights); the inputs are considered fixed. Thus, it doesn't matter how many inputs you are adding the costs of: This simply changes the scalar cost value that backprop starts with at the output layer. The actual propagation stays the same (just with different values).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I agree that the forward pass is the same but I am still confused about the backwards pass. If I write train_cross_entropy2 = tf.stop_gradients(train_cross_entropy2) and then say that train_cross_entropy = train_cross_entropy2 + train_cross_entropy1 then the time is back to being fast. Doesn't this prove that 2 backwards passes are happening in the original code since the forward passes will still be the same?

Comment: That's interesting! What I could imagine is happening: During training, the costs aren't really interesting (unless we are doing something with them such as plotting); all we care about are the gradients. So maybe if you use `tf.stop_gradients(train_cross_entropy2)` the *forward pass* for the second input will never be executed since it's not needed (since the gradient is ignored). This would explain the faster execution.  However I have to admit I'm really no expert regarding Tensorflow's low-level execution model, so this is just speculation.

Comment: I think the forward pass must still be happening twice since the cross_entropy_loss is being evaluated in sess.run (it is being evaluated as twice what it would be if I did not add the two which makes sense). I will keep digging!